# Azure table store REST OData not supporting for $count and $orderby

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am working on invoking Azure storage table with OData based REST service calls from HTTP client.

Normals query works well but when I query using $count, $inlinecount, $orderBy, I am getting below exceptions.

```
The ability of the data service to return row count information is disabled. To enable this functionality, set the DataServiceConfiguration.AcceptCountRequests property to true.
```

and

```
The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource.
```

I am confused where to enabled this functionality, Can some one please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused where to enabled this functionality.

Simple answer is that you can't.

Azure Tables has limited support for OData query options and it only supports `$filter`, `$select` and `$top` query options.

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#supported-query-options.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will query with in available features list.